# Почему в русском и украинском языках существуют разные названия для старых народных сказов?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Мне интересно, почему в русском сохранились былины о богатырях, а в украинском древнейшее сказание - это о казаке Мамае? (думаю, имя Мамай, у большинства русских вызывает некоторые воспоминания)

---

Вопрос из [ответа](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/28467/2) участника [@sonntag](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/2586/sonntag).

Answer (score 4):

Былины, что киевского, что новгородского цикла почти полностью вымерли к XIX в., когда их стали записывать. Единственное место, где они сохранились, это Русский Север, Олонецкая губерния. Учёные объсняют это прежде всего тем, что из-за долгих зим на Русском Севере у людей появлялось много свободного времени, которое и заполняли длинными сказаниями и былинами. На юге же жизнь была активнее и подобные жанры забылись.

Answer (score 1):

Ну для начала, это два разных Мамая, хотя есть весьма аргументированная гипотеза, что прообраз казака Мамая надо искать среди потомков огузов - группы тюркоговорящих племен, значительной частью ставших одним из этносов Орды. Но это объясняет только фонетическое сходство имен, достоверных данных о том нет.

Ну а что касается легенд... Я думаю тут все просто. Прямая линия фольклорного жанра прервалась со вхождением Киева с состав Великого княжества Литовского, что в свою очередь положило начало формированию украинской нации. Новый народ - новые сказки. Собственно, русская нация тоже сильно преобразилась с момента потери Киева. Но, как верно пишет Марк Из, внешние условия были более благоприятными для сохранения преемственности культуры и традиции.

Впрочем, легенды времен Киевской Руси украинские наука и культура тоже причисляют к своему наследию. Так что утверждение, что у них нет ничего раньше казака Мамая, весьма дискуссионно.

Answer (score 0):

Да, достоверных данных нет - родословец князей Глинских к таковым не относится.

Согласно нему, разбитый верными законному царю Тохтамышу войсками темник Мамай бежал в Крым, где и был убит. Его сыновья убоялись царского гнева и ушли на север, в район Полтавы. Один из них вернулся к Тохтамышу, а другой остался - ушел из рода, стал казаком (в татарской терминологии) - и основал княжество. В начальной стадии этногенеза группы людей именуются по имени предводителя. Вот и появились казаки Мамаи (порядки в княжестве были весьма демократичными). Княжество вошло в состав Литвы как Глинское, а со временем княжна из этого рода стала правительницей Москвы и матерью Ивана Грозного

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что большинство русских былин  [кодифицированы в девятнадцатом веке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) на письме, а украинские [думы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0_(%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81)) передавались как устная бардовская традиция с четырнадцатого века и исчезли вместе с носителями традиции - [кобзарями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%85).